# change start menu name during minor version upgrade in installshield

Tags: installshield-2011

Currently, in program start menu I have as below 
             Program Menu - [XXX] - Product name

Now , I want to change as 
             Program Menu - [YYY] - Product name

How to change start menu name during minor version upgrade in installshield?
Is it possible to do this during minor upgrade?
Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved something similar for setting the name of my short cut folder based on property decided at run time. I wouldn't know how to change the name of an existing folder though I take it you are looking to rename the folder from something like 'Product v10' to 'Product v11'

When you add the [XXX] directory name, give is a name such as ShortcutCompanyName.

Then add a 'Set Directory' custom action (type 35) that changes sets:

```
    Directory Name : ShortcutCompanyName
    Directory Value: [ProgramMenuFolder]\[MyShortCutFolder]
    Install UI Sequence: After CostFinalize
    Install Exec Sequence: After CostFinalize
    Admin UI Sequence: After CostFinalize
    Admin Exec Sequence: After CostFinalize
```

Where [MyShortCutFolder] is a property I have set to the name of the folder I want i.e. XXX or YYY in your case.